# How to use type DATE with laravel php

Tags: php, forms, laravel, date

I'm very new using Laravel and I have a problem with a column that I created in the migrations. I have a column that is type date. My problem is that I don't know how can I manage it, how do I have to store some data for a form, etc.

I was asking if someone could tell me, in a method of a controller with the parameter Resquest $r, how can a convert the string from that form in a variable of date. I've been searching and I can't find anything that could help me. Thanks in advance!

Edit:

This is one method of my controller:

```
public function addObjectives(Request $r,$id){

    $gobjectives = Mgobjective::all();
    $sobjectives = Msobjective::all();

    $mprogram = Mprogram::find($id);
    $a = Area::find($mprogram->marea_id);

    if($a==null){
        $area = new Area();
        $area->id = $mprogram->marea_id;
        $area->saveArea();
    }

    $p = Program::find($id);

    if($p==null){
        $program = new Program();
        $program->id = $id;
        $program->initialDate= "";
        $program->finalDate= "";
        $program->frequency= "";
        $program->area_id = $mprogram->marea_id;
        $program->saveProgram();
    }
}
```

In initialDate y finalDate de program, I have an empty string because before it was a string. I would like to put there a date that doesn't have to be the actual date.

Comment: please show your code to get quick solution

Comment: I'd just did it, thanks for helping!

Comment: @KaliaMartinReina Welcome to StackOverflow! Instead of adding "SOLVED" to the question title, you should accept one of the answers below that *actually solves* your problem. Please read this: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/255183)

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `date()` function like:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('your date'));
```

**Explanation:** `Y-m-d` is the default date format for mysql `date` type. So what ever formated date you have, convert it into `Y-m-d`.

Comment: I'd works, thank you very much! But now that I know how to do this, I have another question. If I want to change the default date form and I'd like to put it like 'd-m-Y', what would I have to do? I asking about the database. Thanks again.

Comment: Its not a good approach, just change the format in script language and save it in database.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class YourController extends Controller
{
    public function yourMethod(Request $request)
    {
        // If you use a HTML date element, you "should" receive the data in yyyy-mm-dd
        // format which can be understood by DateTime's constructor
        $date = new \DateTime($request->input('date'));

        // If you use a different input or expect a date in a different format you can
        // use the createFromFormat method, where your first parameter is the date
        // format you expect and the second is the date input.
        $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->input('date'));

        // Once your date has been loaded into a DateTime object, you can use the
        // format method to output the date in any format you like. MySQL and other
        // databases tend to expect and store dates in yyyy-mm-dd format.
        echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand it!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/)

```
Carbon::createFromDate($year, $month, $day, $tz);
```

or

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H', '1975-05-21 22')->toDateTimeString(); // 1975-05-21 22:00:00
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)